# JQuery Select on Dynamically Created Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

Hi I am creating some dynamic

elements here

```
function loadApiData(){
var url, jqxhr, url2, jqxhr2, status;
for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    url2 = document.URL + 'status/' + i;
    jqxhr2 = $.getJSON(url2, function(data) {
        console.log('API response received');
        //console.log(url2);
        console.log(data);
        status = data['status'];
        //console.log(status);
        if (status == false) {
            //$('#false').append('<p class="p2" id="' + data['phone'] + 'on">' + data['phone'] + ' phone Status: ' + status + '<p>');
            $('#false').append('<p class="p2" id="' + data['phone'] + 'on">' + data['phone'] + ' phone Status: <input type="button" id="' + data['phone'] + 'off" value="' + status + '" /><p>');
        } else {
            $('#true').append('<p id="' + data['phone'] + 'off">' + data['phone'] + ' phone Status: ' + status + '<p>');
        }
    });
}

};
```

However when I then try loading them later

```
function loadWindowSystem() {
 $('#Nimoff').click(function() {
    alert('hi');
});
};
```

I find that it doesn't actually register the click event.

My document.ready() looks like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
loadApiData();
loadWindowSystem();
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

**Resolved by using**

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '#Nimoff', function () { // you code });
```

Comment: Try using `$('#Nimoff').on('click', function() { alert('hi');});`

Comment: `$( document ).on( 'click', '#Nimoff', function () {
   // you code
});`

Comment: Thanks @ozil can you make your answer an answer so I can mark it as correct, yours did the tick.

Comment: @ Nim i am not getting answer option. you can vote up

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind the event -

```
$('#false').append('<p class="p2" id="' + data['phone'] + 'on">' + data['phone'] + ' phone Status: <input type="button" id="' + data['phone'] + 'off" value="' + status + '" /><p>').bind('click', function() {
    alert('hii');
});
```

Or try with -

```
$('#Nimoff').on('click', function() {  ............ //code here })
```